# API process blocking map and interactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm in the process of building an iOS app (6.0+), and the flow works like this:

1. Touch the app icon
2. App begins loading, brings up first view (a map view)
3. Once app has location, gets information on it from an API via http request
4. Uses that data to fill out some map annotations

I find that at 2, the app stops responding altogether until the end of 4. It feels like a broken experience, and like the app has frozen until it completes adding the annotations.

How can I get around this blocking behavior? I suspect the answer has something to do with how I thread my tasks, but I don't know really where to look, or if it's actually the problem I should be solving.

Comment: You're probably doing networking on the main thread. That's a no-no. use a framework like AFNetworking for async callbacks, or use NSURLConnection's `+sendAsynchronousRequest:` method.

Comment: You're absolutely right; I feel so dumb. Why do they even have a synchronous URL Request option?

Comment: It's a support method. It used to be really hard to just get the data returned by a NSURLConnection, so they added that as a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use asynchrone request to get the data from the server, otherwise the application will wait till the request has finished.

you could use one of the following class methods of NSURLConnection

[connectionWithRequest:delegate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest%3adelegate%3a)

[sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a)

or use a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: If you could flesh out your answer a bit more (maybe using the actual selector names), I'd be happy to give you the green check.